# AMD ordering is different in Matlab vs Eigen library

Tags: r, matlab, linear-algebra, rcpp, eigen

Even though functions for Approximate minimum degree permutation seem to be based on the same underlying code for Eigen [[1](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/e4993e883ad15a5bd2b5f77a7cb5369efaa5b7c9/Eigen/src/OrderingMethods/Amd.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), [2](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AMDOrdering.html)] and Matlab [[3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/amd.html)] (Timothy A. Davis's code packaged in the Suite Sparse library) I'm getting different results on the same data matrix, when calling the Eigen routines through the RcppEigen package.

Here's a minimal example with matlab/octave code (which give the same results) and Eigen, called through the inline interface.

Matlab/Octave:

```
A = gallery('wathen',2,2);
p = amd(A);
save('amddemo.mat', 'A', 'p')
```

R

```
library(RcppEigen)
library(inline)

amdCpp <- '
using Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;

const SparseMatrix<double> A(as<SparseMatrix<double> >(AA));
Eigen::AMDOrdering<int> ordering;
Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, int> perm;
ordering(A.selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>(), perm);
return wrap(Eigen::MatrixXd(perm));'


rcppeigen_amd <- cxxfunction(signature(AA = "dgCMatrix"),
                       amdCpp, plugin = "RcppEigen")

library(R.matlab)
demo <- readMat('amddemo.mat')
p    <- rcppeigen_amd(demo$A)
apply(p, 2, function(x) which(x==1))
[1] 16 20 21 14 15 17 18 19  1  2  6 10  9  3  4  5  8 12 13  7 11
demo$p[1,]
[1] 14 17 18 16 20 21 15 19  4  5  8 12 13  1  2  3  6  7  9 11 1
```

The ordering roughly similar, but not identical and I'm wondering if one of these should be considered out of date?

As mentioned, the Matlab help page for amd function says "AMD Version 2.0 is written and copyrighted by Timothy A. Davis"

Using versions Matlab R2015b (8.6.0.267246) 64-bit (glnxa64) and RcppEigen_0.3.2.7.0

Thanks!

EDITS:
 Due to [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel)'s comment, I have creating the following scripts to test the code independently of RcppEigen. Here is the [C++ code](https://gist.github.com/zdk123/9c623b6bdf3a57018ae2) (which generates some random data and performs the ordering) and an [octave script](https://gist.github.com/zdk123/f76f539ddfe0541b20d7) to read in the the output of the C++ script and compare the solutions. I have not yet testing the script with matlab yet. And, for compatibility, I linked to RcppEigen's copy of Eigen when compiling.

From linux bash:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include/ amdtest.cpp -o amdtest
amdtest > dat.txt
octave -qf amdtest.m dat.txt
```

Example output is

```
1    2    4    5    6    8   15    3    7    9   10   11   12   13   14

5    9    4    7   10    2    8   15   11    6   12   14   13    1    3
```

Where the first solution is from the Eigen library and the second is from Octave.

Comment: Can you also post the numerical results

Comment: added, though the data is randomly generated, I believe, so ymmv.

Comment: The Eigen's version diverged from the original code to handle semi-definite matrices having some explicit zeros on the diagonal. That's the main change I can remember.

Comment: Can you also try 'plain Eigen' as a C++ program just to exclude that we do something silly in the creation of the sparse matrix?

Comment: Did this and added the code/results in the edits. I also adjusting the AMD code so as to not rely on the selfadjoint operator. Doesn't seem to help though.